# Cache dynamic images better

Tags: php, http-headers

I am creating images dynamically, on my page, and I am telling the browser to cache the images, which works. But when I press <kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh the page, the images reload, and they shouldn't do that. Here is the HTML that I am using:

```
<img width="240" height="240"
src="/user-data/images/image.php?id=2&file=1234567890&height=240&width=240" />
```

And here are is the PHP headers portion:

```
header("Cache-Control: private, max-age=172800, pre-check=172800");
header("Pragma: private");
// Set to expire in 2 days
header("Expires: " . date(DATE_RFC822, strtotime(" 2 days")));
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'])){
    // if the browser has a cached version of this image, send 304
    header('Last-Modified: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'], true, 304);
    exit;
}
```

So, is this something I can control when someone press <kbd>F5</kbd>? Am I missing something from my headers?

Comment: Are you concerned about the image reloading (bandwidth problem) or by the script generating the same image again (server load problem)?

Comment: If you hit F5, I know some browsers tend to retrieve everything again regardless of caching headers. However, if you browse around using hyperlinks (even away from the page and back again), the browser uses the cache properly. Might be worth checking before you try to fix a problem that may not exist :)

Comment: I just don't like that it takes a while to load the image. when it should be in cached.

Comment: I did find out that `HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE` isn't being set.

Comment: One thing I did, was turn down the image quality from 100 to 75, and that really speed things up!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fastcgi - put theese lines in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE:%{HTTP:If-Modified-Since}]
```

And the `$_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']` will be available.